# Shift by ex units in 3d tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, dimensions, unit-of-measure

In 2D coordinates (red image), I can use `ex` units to shift a node:

```
\path (1,0) ++ (1.0ex,0) node {$x$};
```

But, when attempting to do the same thing with 3D coordinates (blue image),

```
\path (1,0,0) ++ (1.0ex,0,0) node {$x$};
```

this gets a bit wacky.  I suspect that this is related to the transformation matrix that maps the 3D coordinate onto a 2D display. But, how can I shift a fixed amount with 3D coordinates.

Each of the axis labels below were intended to be shifted by `1.0ex` from the tip:

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\newcommand*{\Offset}{1.0ex}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[ultra thick, red, ->]
    \draw (0,0) -- (1,0);
    \path (1,0) ++ (\Offset,0) node {$x$};
    
    \draw (0,0) -- (0,1);
    \path (0,1) ++ (0,\Offset) node {$y$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\quad
\begin{tikzpicture}[ultra thick, blue, ->]
    \draw (0,0,0) -- (1,0,0);
    \path (1,0,0) ++ (\Offset,0,0) node {$x$};
    
    \draw (0,0,0) -- (0,1,0);
    \path (0,1,0) ++ (0,\Offset,0) node {$y$};
    
    \draw (0,0,0) -- (0,0,1);
    \path (0,0,1) ++ (0,0,\Offset) node {$z$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't you just want to lose the units?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{xcolor}


\newcommand{\Offset}{.3}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[ultra thick, red, ->]
    \draw (0,0) -- (1,0);
    \path (1,0) ++ (\Offset,0) node {$x$};

    \draw (0,0) -- (0,1);
    \path (0,1) ++ (0,\Offset) node {$y$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\quad
\begin{tikzpicture}[ultra thick, blue, ->]
    \draw (0,0,0) -- (1,0,0);
    \path (1,0,0) ++ (\Offset,0,0) node {$x$};

    \draw (0,0,0) -- (0,1,0);
    \path (0,1,0) ++ (0,\Offset,0) node {$y$};

    \draw (0,0,0) -- (0,0,1);
    \path (0,0,1) ++ (0,0,\Offset) node {$z$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Yeah that will work for _most_ cases, but if one changes the unit vectors, try adding `x=0.5cm, y=3cm` to the `tikzpicture` options, then using a fixed distance is better.

Comment: @PeterGrill don't confuse me with these tikz technicalities otherwise I'll post a picture mode answer instead:-) (I suggest you accept the other answer in anycase)

Answer (score 1):

I defined tree functions (`lengthto3dx`, `lengthto3dy` and `lengthto3dz`) to convert a length to x, y or z units.

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\makeatletter
\tikzset{
  declare function={
    lengthto3dx(\x) = \x/veclen(\the\pgf@xx,\the\pgf@xy);
    lengthto3dy(\y) = \y/veclen(\the\pgf@yx,\the\pgf@yy);
    lengthto3dz(\z) = \z/veclen(\the\pgf@zx,\the\pgf@zy);
  },
}
\makeatother

\newcommand*{\Offset}{1ex}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[ultra thick, red, ->]
    \draw (0,0) -- (1,0);
    \path (1,0) ++ (\Offset,0) node {$x$};

    \draw (0,0) -- (0,1);
    \path (0,1) ++ (0,\Offset) node {$y$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\quad
\begin{tikzpicture}[ultra thick, blue, ->,x=.5cm,y=3cm,z=-2cm]
    \draw (0,0,0) -- (1,0,0);
    \path (1,0,0) ++ ({lengthto3dx(\Offset)},0,0) node {$x$};

    \draw (0,0,0) -- (0,1,0);
    \path (0,1,0) ++ (0,{lengthto3dy(\Offset)},0) node {$y$};

    \draw (0,0,0) -- (0,0,1);
    \path (0,0,1) ++ (0,0,{lengthto3dz(\Offset)}) node {$z$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}[ultra thick, blue, ->]
    \draw (0,0,0) -- (1,0,0);
    \path (1,0,0) ++ ({lengthto3dx(\Offset)},0,0) node {$x$};

    \draw (0,0,0) -- (0,1,0);
    \path (0,1,0) ++ (0,{lengthto3dy(\Offset)},0) node {$y$};

    \draw (0,0,0) -- (0,0,1);
    \path (0,0,1) ++ (0,0,{lengthto3dz(\Offset)}) node {$z$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```